# Snowflake kafka connector failing after initializing TEST connector

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

Not sure what is wrong. Trying to setup Snowflake kafka connect and it seems to be failing without throwing any useful logs

> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,024] INFO Creating connector TEST_CONNECTOR of type com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:202)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,028] INFO Instantiated connector TEST_CONNECTOR with version 1.5.0 of type class com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:205)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,029] INFO
> [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Snowflake Kafka Connector Version: 1.5.0 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.Utils:99)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,092] WARN
> [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Connector update is available, please upgrade Snowflake Kafka Connector (1.5.0 -> 1.5.2)  (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.Utils:136)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,092] INFO
> [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkConnector:start (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:91)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,330] INFO
> [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] initialized the snowflake connection (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1:38)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,336] INFO Finished creating connector TEST_CONNECTOR (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:224)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,337] INFO Skipping reconfiguration of connector sflksink since it is not running (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:285)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,338] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone$1.onCompletion(ConnectStandalone.java:104)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone$1.onCompletion(ConnectStandalone.java:98)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.onCompletion(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:44)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:185)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:107)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,340] INFO Kafka Connect stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:65)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,341] INFO Stopping REST server (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:211)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,345] INFO Stopped http_8083@2cc0fa2a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:306)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,354] INFO Stopped o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c83ae01{/,null,UNAVAILABLE} (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:865)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,360] INFO REST server stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:222)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,360] INFO Herder stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:77)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,360] INFO Stopping connector TEST_CONNECTOR (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:305)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,361] INFO
> [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] SnowflakeSinkConnector:stop (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector:141)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,362] INFO Stopped connector TEST_CONNECTOR (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:321)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,362] INFO Worker stopping (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:151)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,365] INFO Stopped FileOffsetBackingStore (org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore:67)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,365] INFO Worker stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:172)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,369] INFO Herder stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder:87)
> [2021-04-07 21:09:25,371] INFO Kafka Connect stopped (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:70)

The config file looks like below

```
name=sflksink
connector.class=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=snowflake-connect-test
buffer.count.records=10
buffer.flush.time=60
buffer.size.bytes=50
snowflake.url.name=url
snowflake.user.name=<user>
snowflake.database.name=<database>
snowflake.schema.name=<schema>
snowflake.private.key=<private_key>
snowflake.warehouse.name=MY_WAREHOUSE
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeJsonConverter
```

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: What Kafka version are you using?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 2.11-1.1.0

Comment: If you're not able to upgrade that, is there connect-log4j.properties file you can modify to change the logs to debug? Does the same error occur with connect-distributed?

Comment: In distributed mode I do not get error but I do not see my connector as well when using `curl localhost:8083/connectors`

Comment: @OneCricketeer any other suggestion?

Comment: You'll have to HTTP POST the connector json, it's not started automatically like with the standalone script

Answer (score 0):

In the log message it says

```
Connector update is available, please upgrade Snowflake Kafka Connector (1.5.0 -> 1.5.2)
```

So I would suggest that you update your connector JAR to the latest version and try again.

Comment: Shouldn't connector tasks be isolated enough not to cause an internal NPE?

Comment: @RobinThe latest one is not available to us because of the artifacts repository limitations. Do you strongly think this could be an issue?